# Nesting looped components in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, loops, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm new to Vue framework and i'm trying to insert a for loop, based on a component, inside a parent for loop. I've passed 2 days testing different ways to do that but it still doesn't work.

The app I'm trying to build should give the user the possibility to create a quizz. He could add a new "question" form by clicking on a button. Every question block contains, by default, an answer input. By clicking on another button, the user can increases the number of answer input on the chosen question block.

The code which is above makes a question input appears on the browser, the addQuestion function which creates a new question block works too, but the answer input that should be under the question input is not there. Furthermore, the browser console doesn't return any error.

Could someone help me to understand what is wrong in my code please ?

Thanks by advance.

```js
let questionblock = Vue.component('questionblock', {
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  data: function() {
      return {
          id_count:1,
          answers: [
              {id:1}
          ]        
      }
  },
  props: ['question_prop'],
  methods: {
      addQuestion:  function() {
              ++app.id_question;
              let new_id = app.id_question;
              app.questions.push({id: new_id});
          },
      removeQuestion: function() {
              --app.id_question;
              app.questions.pop();
          }
  },
  template: '<div class="block-question">'                   
              +'<legend>Question [[ question_prop.id ]]</legend>'
              +'<span class="num-question d-inline-block">[[ question_prop.id ]]</span>'
              +'<textarea class="form-control question-control d-inline-block" name="question" placeholder="Entrez votre question"></textarea>'
              +'<i class="fas fa-plus-circle" v-on:click="addQuestion"></i>'
              +'<i class="fas fa-trash" v-on:click="removeQuestion"></i>'
          +'</div>'

});

let answerblock = Vue.component('answerblock', {
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  props: ['answer_prop'],
  template: '<div class="block-answer">'
              +'<span class="num-answer d-inline-block">[[ answer_prop.id ]]</span>'
              +'<textarea class="form-control answer-control d-inline-block" type="text" name="" placeholder="Entrez votre réponse"></textarea>'
              +'<i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>'
              +'<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>'
          +'</div>'
});

var app = new Vue({
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  components: {questionblock, answerblock},
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      id_question: 1,
      questions: [
          {
              id: 1,
              answers: [{id:0}]
          }
      ],
  },
});
```

```html
<div id="app" class="col main-content">
    <questionblock
    v-for="question in questions"
    v-bind:question_prop="question"
    v-bind:id_question="id_question"
    v-bind:key="question.id">
        <answerblock 
        v-for="answer in question.answers"
        v-bind:answer_prop="answer"
        v-bind:key="answer.id">
        </answerblock>
    </questionblock>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to have the `<answerblock>` component tag within the `<questionblock>` tag, you'll need to provide a `<slot>` tag in template definition of the question component. [Here's the documentation on slots.](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html)

Comment: Or add the `<answerblock>` directly to `<questionblock>`'s template.

Comment: ok it works now, thanks a lot for your help